# r create new variable instead of mutate

Tags: r

I am working on BMI calculations. I have the following code

```
mutate(name, bmi = mass / ((height / 100)  ^ 2)) %>%
  mutate(BMI_Value = ifelse(bmi > median(bmi, na.rm = T), "Above Average BMI", "Below Average BMI")) %>% 
  select(name, contains("bmi"))
```

If I use mutate like this, then I can't use the BMI_Value later on. So I was wondering how I could maybe creaet a new variable to be able to use again

---

Follow on update

---

Ok see this code below, this runs fine but I can't seem to use bmi again

```
starwars.df <- starwars
head(starwars)

starwars %>% 
  mutate(name, bmi = mass / ((height / 100)  ^ 2))
```

Then when I try and create bmi like below I get an error, see below after code

```
starwars.df <- starwars
head(starwars)

 
starwars$bmi <-  mutate(bmi = mass / ((height / 100)  ^ 2))
```

Error in mutate(mass, bmi = mass/((height/100)^2)) :
object 'mass' not found

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. I've read this and I don't know if `name` is a data-frame, or a variable name.
Also, this should work as is, so there is something you've left out, that breaks things. If `name` is a data-frame, and then this might cause the issue.

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is. You create a column with mutate, then drop it with select, but then you want it back again...? If you want the column, don't get rid of it

Comment: I think the main issue is that you are printing the result, not updating the `name` data frame. If I have `x <- 5` and I run the line `x + 1`, the result `6` will print, but `x` is still `5`. If I want to change `x`, I use `x <- x + 1` to assign the modification. The same idea applies with `mutate`, if you want the `name` data frame to be updated you need to assign the modification, `name <- mutate(name ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though it is not completely clear to me what you are doing, maybe the issue is that you are not saving your operations in an object (your dataframe).
Try to add `-> new_df` at the end of the last row to save everything in a new data frame. It should then contain all newly created variables.

Also, remove `name` in the select step: `select(contains("bmi"))`

---

**Update after updated question:**

the pipe operator `%>%` does not save your dataframe, so you just need to assign your operations to your dataframe again (or to a new one...):

```
starwars <- starwars %>% 
  mutate(bmi = mass / ((height / 100)  ^ 2))
```

or alternatively:

```
starwars %>% 
      mutate(bmi = mass / ((height / 100)  ^ 2)) -> starwars
```